# Runnable method stops after one time

Tags: java, android, timer, onclick, runnable

I built a small app that u write a number of secs and then there is a timer. when the timer comes to 0 it plays music.
Unfortunately the `Runnable` stops after one substract (I mean that after I wrote 5 and Pressed the button the 5 substracted to 4 and stops then.)
I cannot write the `Runnable` outside the `onClick` because I need that it will run only after the user clicks the START button.
How can I do that?
Here's my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   // btnPlant.setEnabled(false);
    handler = new Handler();
    while(count >0) {
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count = Integer.parseInt(etInput.getText().toString());
                count--;
                timer.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `postDelayed` *lots* of times - because in your loop itself you're not changing `count`. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but this doesn't look like the right way of doing it...

Comment: Finally I solved it , I moved the count = Integer.parseInt(etInput.getText().toString()); outside the Runnable and in the OnClick. Thank you

Comment: Be sure to answer your own question, then accept your own answer as the correct one.  That's perfectly acceptable (and expected) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the line

```
 count = Integer.parseInt(etInput.getText().toString());
```

outside the Runnable, because the problem was that I always passed to the count the value of the edittext which does not change, like 5 .
After that I substract 1 from 5 so its 4 and print. 
And again sending it the value of 5, it becomes 4 and again and again.. so:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // btnPlant.setEnabled(false);

        handler = new Handler();
        count = Integer.parseInt(etInput.getText().toString());

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                count--;
                timer.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };


        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
```